# Como optimizar esta consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, join

Estoy consultando en una tabla de más de 10 millones de registros la cuál funciona bien con otras consultas, pero esta en especial demora más de 15 minutos, paso a creer que es por que es por los LEFT JOIN ON. Como podría optimizar esta consulta??? que me sugieren?

Los valores de la consulta sql son necesarios para realizar ciertas validaciones de tiempos, esto pertenece a la medición de turneros en tiempo de atención y demás.

```
 select *
    from( select b.fechahora, a.idturno as turno, pd.nombre as puntoD, c.idturnoasociado as turnoasociado, aa.descripcion as ultimo_estado, z.descripcion as prioridad, a.fechahora as ingreso, k.fechahora as activadonoaplica, b.fechahora as atiende, coalesce(o.nombreusuario, '') as usuario_atiende, g.fechahora as termina, coalesce(q.nombreusuario, '') as usuario_termina, h.fechahora as cancela, coalesce(s.nombreusuario, 'sistema') as usuario_cancela, i.fechahora as asociado, j.fechahora as noaplica, coalesce(u.nombreusuario, '') as usuario_noaplica, l.fechahora as terminadopendiente, coalesce(w.nombreusuario, 'sistema') as usuario_pendiente, m.fechahora as cambio_a_preferencial, y.nombreusuario as usuario_cambiapreferencial, timediff(b.fechahora, a.fechahora) as ingresa_atiende, timediff(g.fechahora, b.fechahora) as atiende_termina, timediff(h.fechahora, b.fechahora) as atiende_cancela, timediff(i.fechahora, a.fechahora) as ingresa_asociado, timediff(j.fechahora, b.fechahora) as atiende_noaplica, timediff(b.fechahora, k.fechahora) as activadonoaplica_atiende, timediff(l.fechahora, b.fechahora) as atiende_teminadopendiente, concat_ws(' ', d.primernombre, d.primerapellido) as cliente, f.abreviatura as tipodocumento, d.documento
    from turnoH a
    left join turnoH b on
    (a.idturno = b.idturno
        and b.idturnoestado = 2)
    left join turnoH g on
    (a.idturno = g.idturno
        and g.idturnoestado = 3)
    left join turnoH h on
    (a.idturno = h.idturno
        and h.idturnoestado = 4)
    left join turnoH i on
    (a.idturno = i.idturno
        and i.idturnoestado = 5)
    left join turnoH j on
    (a.idturno = j.idturno
        and j.idturnoestado = 6)
    left join turnoH k on
    (a.idturno = k.idturno
        and k.idturnoestado = 7)
    left join turnoH l on
    (a.idturno = l.idturno
        and l.idturnoestado = 8)
    left join turnoH m on
    (a.idturno = m.idturno
        and m.idturnoestado = 9)
    join turno c on
    (a.idturno = c.idturno)
    join entidad d
        using(identidad)
    join tipodedocumento f
        using(idtipodedocumento)
    left join turnocajausuario n on
    (b.idturnocajausuario = n.idturnocajausuario)
    left join usuarios o on
    (n.idusuarios = o.idusuarios)
    left join turnocajausuario p on
    (g.idturnocajausuario = p.idturnocajausuario)
    left join usuarios q on
    (q.idusuarios = p.idusuarios)
    left join turnocajausuario r on
    (h.idturnocajausuario = r.idturnocajausuario)
    left join usuarios s on
    (s.idusuarios = r.idusuarios)
    left join turnocajausuario t on
    (j.idturnocajausuario = t.idturnocajausuario)
    left join usuarios u on
    (u.idusuarios = t.idusuarios)
    left join turnocajausuario v on
    (l.idturnocajausuario = v.idturnocajausuario)
    left join usuarios w on
    (w.idusuarios = v.idusuarios)
    left join turnocajausuario x on
    (m.idturnocajausuario = x.idturnocajausuario)
    left join usuarios y on
    (y.idusuarios = x.idusuarios)
    join turnoprioridad z on
    (a.idturnoprioridad = z.idturnoprioridad)
    JOIN turnoestado aa on
    (aa.idturnoestado = c.idturnoestadoactual)
    JOIN puntoD pd on
    (pd.idpuntoD = c.idpuntoD)
    where a.idturnoestado = 1 /* and b.fechahora is not null*/
    and a.fechahora >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
    and a.fechahora <= '2021-07-01 23:59:59'
    and pd.idpuntoD = 99944
    order by a.idturno )tempo
    WHERE fechahora IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: yo partiría por eliminar el ``SELECT * FROM () tempo WHERE fechahora IS NOT NULL`` ya que ese dato lo puedes obtener directamente en tu subconsulta. agregando a tu WHERE ``AND a.fechahora IS NOT NULL``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema principal es que estás leyendo las tablas demasiadas veces cuando puedes hacerlo una sola vez. Dejo un ejemplo de como evitar esto mediante un agregado condicional. El código puede tener errores ya que no tengo forma de probarlo.

```
SELECT   ts.atiende AS fechahora
        ,ts.idturno AS turno
        ,pd.nombre AS puntoD
        ,t.idturnoasociado AS turnoasociado
        ,te.descripcion AS ultimo_estado
        ,tp.descripcion AS prioridad
        ,ts.ingreso
        ,ts.activadonoaplica
        ,ts.atiende
        ,ts.usuario_atiende
        ,ts.termina
        ,ts.usuario_termina
        ,ts.cancela
        ,ts.usuario_cancela
        ,ts.asociado
        ,ts.noaplica
        ,ts.usuario_noaplica
        ,ts.terminadopendiente
        ,ts.usuario_pendiente
        ,ts.cambio_a_preferencial
        ,ts.usuario_cambiapreferencial
        ,timediff( ts.atiende, ts.ingreso) AS ingresa_atiende
        ,timediff( ts.termina, ts.atiende) AS atiende_termina
        ,timediff( ts.cancela, ts.atiende) AS atiende_cancela
        ,timediff( ts.asociado, ts.ingreso) AS ingresa_asociado
        ,timediff( ts.noaplica, ts.atiende) AS atiende_noaplica
        ,timediff( ts.atiende, ts.activadonoaplica) AS activadonoaplica_atiende
        ,timediff( ts.terminadopendiente, ts.atiende) AS atiende_teminadopendiente
        ,concat_ws(' ', e.primernombre, e.primerapellido) AS cliente
        ,td.abreviatura AS tipodocumento
        ,e.documento
FROM (  SELECT th.turnoid,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 1 THEN th.fechahora END) AS ingreso,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 2 THEN th.fechahora END) AS atiende,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 3 THEN th.fechahora END) AS termina,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 4 THEN th.fechahora END) AS cancela,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 5 THEN th.fechahora END) AS asociado,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 6 THEN th.fechahora END) AS noaplica,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 7 THEN th.fechahora END) AS activadonoaplica,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 8 THEN th.fechahora END) AS terminadopendiente,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 9 THEN th.fechahora END) AS cambio_a_preferencial,
            COALESCE(MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 2 THEN u.nombreusuario END), '')        AS usuario_atiende,
            COALESCE(MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 3 THEN u.nombreusuario END), '')        AS usuario_termina,
            COALESCE(MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 4 THEN u.nombreusuario END), 'sistema') AS usuario_cancela,
            COALESCE(MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 6 THEN u.nombreusuario END), '')        AS usuario_noaplica,
            COALESCE(MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 8 THEN u.nombreusuario END), 'sistema') AS usuario_pendiente,
            MAX( CASE WHEN th.idturnoestado = 9 THEN nombreusuario END) AS usuario_cambiapreferencial
        FROM turnoH                th
        LEFT JOIN turnocajausuario tcu ON th.idturnocajausuario = tcu.idturnocajausuario
        LEFT JOIN usuarios         u   ON tcu.idusuarios = u.idusuarios
        WHERE th.turnoID IN( SELECT i.turnoID
                             FROM turnoH
                             WHERE i.fechahora >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
                             AND   i.fechahora <= '2021-07-01 23:59:59'
                             AND   i.idturnoestado = 1)
        GROUP BY th.turnoid) ts
JOIN turno           t  ON    ts.idturno = t.idturno
JOIN entidad         e  using (identidad)
JOIN tipodedocumento td using (idtipodedocumento)
JOIN turnoprioridad  tp ON    ts.idturnoprioridad   = tp.idturnoprioridad
JOIN turnoestado     te ON    t.idturnoestadoactual = te.idturnoestado
WHERE pd.idpuntoD = 99944
AND   atiende IS NOT NULL;
```